# mockito using in kotlin, how to use ArgumentCaptor<MutableMap<*, *>> in the test for the function takes Map<String, String>

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, generics, mockito, argumentcaptor

having a test using mockito-inline 3.8.0,
it was using java and converted to kotlin then it got compiler error below:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: (Mutable)Map<String!, String!>?
Found: MutableMap<*, *>!
```

the function to be verified is `logActionEvent(@Nullable Map<String, String> customParams)`

and the ArgumentCaptor is defined as

```
lateinit private var additionalParamCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<MutableMap<*, *>>
ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MutableMap::class.java).also { additionalParamCaptor = it }

or
lateinit private var additionalParamCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<MutableMap<*, *>>
additionalParamCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass<MutableMap<*, *>, MutableMap<*, *>>(MutableMap::class.java)
```

if change from `ArgumentCaptor<MutableMap<*, *>>` to `ArgumentCaptor<Map<*, *>>` the error become:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: (Mutable)Map<String!, String!>?
Found: Map<*, *>!
```

**How to define the ArgumentCaptor?**

here is the related test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class TestK {
    
    lateinit private var eventLogger: EventLogger
    lateinit private var additionalParamCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<MutableMap<*, *>>
    
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        eventLogger = Mockito.spy(EventLogger.getInstance())
        ReflectionHelpers.setStaticField(EventLogger::class.java, "sEventLoggerSingleton", eventLogger)
        ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MutableMap::class.java).also { additionalParamCaptor = it }
    }

    @Test
    @Throws(NoSuchMethodException::class, IllegalAccessException::class, InvocationTargetException::class, InstantiationException::class)
    fun logNotificationOpenEvent() {
        // setup
        val params: Map<String, String?> = HashMap() // = fillMap()
        // fill in the map. i.e.
        params[KEY_MESSAGE_TYPE] = "type"

        // test
        EventLogger.getInstance().logActionEvent(EVENT_NAME_OPEN, params)

        // verify
        Mockito.verify(eventLogger).logActionEvent(ArgumentMatchers.eq(EVENT_NAME_OPEN), additionalParamCaptor.capture()) //<=== does not compile

        val realMap = additionalParamCaptor.value as Map<String, String>
        verifyRivendellMetadata_ShouldExist(realMap, false)
        Assert.assertEquals("type", realMap[KEY_MESSAGE_TYPE])
        ......
    }
}
```

got compiler error:
[image]

the class to be tested

```
public class EventLogger {

public static EventLogger getInstance() {
        if (sEventLoggerSingleton == null) {
            sEventLoggerSingleton = new EventLogger();
        }
        return sEventLoggerSingleton;
    }

public void logActionEvent(@Nullable Map<String, String> customParams) {
        // do logging 
    }
```

Comment: Take a look to mockito-kotlin library, here is their implementation for argumentCaptor: https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin/blob/main/mockito-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/org/mockito/kotlin/ArgumentCaptor.kt

I think it handles your use-case.

In the past I also tried making mockito work with Kotlin and it's kinda painful tbh, I ended up switching to MockK :( 

Good luck!

Comment: Did you fix this issue? Please share the solution if you did

Comment: switch to mockk